# Cocoa Custom Control not visible

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, custom-controls

I try to define a Custom Control in Cocoa like this

```
@IBDesignable
class MyCustomContol: NSControl
{ var textfield: NSTextField!

  required public init?(coder: NSCoder)
  { super.init(coder: coder)

    textfield = NSTextField(frame: self.frame)  
    textfield.backgroundColor = NSColor.yellow
    textfield.stringValue="DEFAULT"
    self.addSubview(textfield)
  }
}
```

In Interfacebuilder I added a Custom View and set its class to my class "MyCustomContol"

The control does not appear in Interfacebuilder an not at runtime.

What´s going wrong.

Comment: That's because you don't instantiate it to create an object through UIVeiwController.

Comment: @ElTomato the control is added in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textfield is invisible in IB, you only see the `NSView`. Runtime you add the textfield with the same frame as the custom control. You don't see it because the textfield is outside the custom control. Set the frame (coordinates in the superview) of the textfield to the bounds (coordinates in the view itself) of the control.

Answer (score 0):

tnx @Willeke

with:

```
textfield = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height) )
```

it works

Comment: `textfield = NSTextField(frame: self.bounds)` should work too.